# bash: test if sort supports -h flag

Tags: bash, flag

I have a function in my bash that has a `sort -h` but on one of my setups `sort` doesn't support the `-h` flag.

How do I test that so I can provide an `else` to have a sort without -h?

Comment: What is the output in a machine with a `sort` that supports it, and in a machine with a `sort` that doesn't? Also, what is the return code of each one? (you can check that running `echo $?` after the command)

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas thanks, that actually answered my question.

Comment: Well... in that case, I'll leave it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the output in a machine with a `sort` that supports it, and in a machine with a `sort` that doesn't. Comparing them may help you understand whether they support the option or not.

You can also check the return code of each one, running `echo $?` after the command. If they differ, you can use that on your favor.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this if statement.

```
if (echo | sort -h > /dev/null 2>&1); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;
```